# How to enlarge tableView on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, tableview

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I tried to review similar questions in SO - still doesn't quite make me understand how to deal with this.

I have a tableView, three textViews and a UIButton. When the user scrolls the tableView, the tableView should pushes the textFields and the button out the image and take up more space. When that is done I want to continue scrolling through the cells.

(I want one of the textFields to always remain and still show the title.)

I think I need to put the textViews and button above the tableView inside a tableView header after which I need to set certain constraints between the UIView above the tableView and tableView itself.  Then I need to play around with the UIScrollViewDelegate and calculate something.

As you guys can probably tell, I'm relatively new in programming and I believe this i why I don't quite understand the related questions. And as you can probably tell too, why I am pretty damn confused about how to solve my problem!

Here's a photo of the VC: 
[image: My-VC]

I wan't the tableView to go and cover the 'AddNewPersonBtn' and the two bottom textView - leaving only the top textView, the navigationBar and the tableView on the screen. --> Until you then scroll down again and the rest will be visible again.

And here goes the code for the VC:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class AllPersonsInYourDiary: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var diary: Diaries?

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var showingDiaryName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var showingDiaryQuestion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var showingExtraIdentifer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var diaryTheme: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var diaryPhoto: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    showDiaryIdentifiers()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func createNewPersonButton () {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
        "PersonViewController") as! PersonViewController
    controller.mode = .create
    controller.diary = diary
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func showEditFunc () {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC") as! SettingsVC
    controller.diary = diary
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}

func showDiaryIdentifiers () {
    self.showingDiaryName.text = diary?.diaryName
    self.showingDiaryQuestion.text = diary?.diaryQuestion
    self.showingExtraIdentifer.text = diary?.diaryExtraIdentifier
    self.diaryTheme.image = UIImage(data: diary?.diaryTheme ?? Data()) ?? UIImage(named: "Blank")
    // self.diaryPhoto.image = UIImage(data: diary?.diaryPhoto ?? Data ()) ?? UIImage(named: "Blank")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return diary!.people.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Person1", for: indexPath) as! PersonCell
    let date = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: (diary?.people[indexPath.row].dateCreated)!, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .none)

    cell.personName.text = diary?.people[indexPath.row].name
    cell.personAnswer.text = date
    cell.personPhoto.image = UIImage(data: diary?.people[indexPath.row].photo ?? Data()) ?? UIImage(named: "PortaitPhoto")

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
        "PersonViewController") as! PersonViewController

    controller.person = diary?.people[indexPath.row]
    controller.diary = diary
    controller.mode = .show
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you wish to delete person?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "No thanks!", style: .cancel)
        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete!", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            guard let person = self.diary?.people[indexPath.row] else {
                return
            }
            self.diary!.people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            realm.delete(person)
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    })
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(action1)
        present(alert, animated: true)
} } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: You mean my whole code for this VC? Or my previous attempts on this issue?

Comment: And maybe a sketch/screenshot of what you want...

Comment: I added a photo of the VC and tried to explain more in detail, what I wish :)

Comment: @AntonBjerg thanks for the photo.  Do you have any code written for the ViewController class?

Comment: @AlexBailey, yeah - about 100 lines.. I can post them all, if that makes it easier to help me? :)

Comment: Yeah please share the code that you've written for this feature.

Comment: @AlexBailey, all my code is now in there too :)